# "But", "but also", "yet", and "and yet" when listing things?

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

How do I express these ideas in Japanese while listing things?

For example, how should these sentences be translated into Japanese while carrying the same tone?

1. He has a scary face but a heart of gold.
2. She's very quiet but also very direct.
3. I was doing my best, and yet I also wanted to give up.
4. I'm excited yet vigilant about the future.
5. You'll have to do it carefully but fast.

Answer (score 5):

I think you have several options. For example...

- けど / けれど / けれども:

> 「彼は顔は怖い**けれど**優しい人です。」
>   「彼女はおとなしい**けど**はっきりものをいう人だ。」

- が:

> 「彼は[強面]{こわもて}だ**が**心は優しい。」
>   「彼女はおとなしい**が**率直な人だ。」

- 一方(で) / 反面、/ (と)同時に / ～が/しかし同時に:

> 「私は将来を楽しみにする**一方で/と同時に**、警戒もしている。」
>   「慎重に、**しかし同時に**素早くしなければいけません。」

- ても / でも:

> 「彼は顔は怖く**ても**、心は優しい。」

- のに:

> 「彼は怖い顔をしている**のに**、優しいですね。」

- ながら / ながらも / つつ / つつも:

> 「未来に期待し**ながらも**、警戒している。」
>   「最善を尽くし**つつ**、やめてしまいたいとも思った。」

- or maybe しかし / それでも / なおかつ / それでいて:

> 「彼女は[物静]{ものしず}かで、**それでいて**率直な人だ。」
>   「慎重に、**それでいて/なおかつ** 素早くやらねばならない。」

Answer (score 1):

I think what in many cases also among your examples make a difference is how strongly one wants to emphasize the contrast, at first, how I would "guess" them:

In 1. I guess the sense of contrast is quite strong; one might not bother to make the statement just because someone looks scary, or just because someone is nice, but only because they came as a set.

In 3-5, I think the sense of contrast is a lot weaker, i.e. just saying "one half" is still meaningful enough.

Giving the above, I would probably use:

1. ...なのに... (Big contrast; なのに may be best translated as despite / even though)
2. (May need more rephrasing, instead of using quiet, I would say　something like) だいたい黙っていますが言う時ははっきり（を？）言う。
3. ...ながら(あきらめ)ようと思った (weak contract, could be translates as while ...ing)
4. ...が... (weak contrast, between "but" and "and")
5. Probably the toughest and depends also on the context, but maybe ても/でも, something like 早くてもていねいにしないと

Answer (score 0):

Japanese has a wide variety of phrases to relate one sentence to the next. For lack of a better term, I'm going to call these words "Sentence-Initial Conjunctions".

でも, equivalent to "however" or "but", is used when the speaker is giving information that shows a contrast to the previous sentence.

As it is said, no matter how much good things you can  tell about someone, if there is a "but", everything goes down to drain. So this "but" is a bit of poison.

In your examples:

---

①

> He has a scary face but a heart of gold.
>   かれ【kare】は【wa】こわい【kowai】かお【kao】 を{o} している【shiteiru】が【ga】、よい【yoi】こころ【kokoro】を【wo】もっている【motteiru】。

As the tone of contrast from the first part of the sentence completely changes after you say "but" likewise the tone of contrast changes after you say いるが【iruga】, here いる【iru】 means "has", and the particle が【ga】 is attached to the last word of the first part of the sentence as a way of differentiating it from the second part of the sentence.

---

②

> She's very quiet but also very direct.
>   かのじょ【kanojo】は【wa】とても【totemo】しずか【shizuka】です【desu】が【ga】、また【mata】 ひじょう【hijou】に【ni】ちょくせつてき【chokusetsuteki】です【desu】。

The particle が【ga】 in です【desu】が【ga】 is the contrasting word "but". When you say the sentence, it will naturally carry the same tone when you speak Japanese fluently. It will slightly vary a bit because of the Japanese accent, but the Japanese people will get the tone you are trying to convey.

There is a certain **pause** of 1 second **after** part  "**She's very quiet**", then it comes the next part "but also very direct" また【mata】 ひじょう【hijou】に【ni】ちょくせつてき【chokusetsuteki】です【desu】. This is the tone we use in English.

In the case of Japanese, there is a **pause after** the particle  **が【ga】** in the clause しずか【shizuka】です【desu】が【ga】.

That is to say, in English the pause comes before the "but", but in Japanese the pause comes after the "が【ga】. Despite the slight variation in tone, Japanese native speakers will get the contrasting tone like the one we have in English.

---

③

> I was doing my best, and yet I also wanted to give up.
>   わたし【Watashi】は【wa】さいぜん【saizen】を【wo】つくしていた【tsukushiteita】が【ga】、それ【sore】でも【demo】わたし【watashi】は 【wa】あきらめたい【akirametai】と【to】おもった【omotta】。

As you can see here as well, there is a が【ga】 right after the word つくしていた【tsukushiteita】. が【ga】 is used as a connector to give contrast between the two sentences, and naturally, there will always be a pause after it and before the contrasting word それでも【soredemo】("and still"/"but still"), which comes later. This is like the small gap we have after the word "best" (??).

---

④

> I am very happy yet not satisfied.
>   わたし【watashi】は【wa】とても【totemo】うれしい【ureshii】です【desu】が【ga】、まんぞく【manzoku】 していない【shiteinai】。

It's the same thing here too. The pause is right after が【ga】 in the construction いるが【iruga】 which means "yet" in the sentence.

---

Note: For most of the contrasting sentences, in Japanese we use が【ga】 for "but", "yet" etc.

I hope this info helped you out. You can try listening to contrasting sentences in Japanese Audio Books online to help you understand better the tone and the pause in the sentences.

Comment: Hmm, I see you translated a lot of the example sentences by breaking the lists into separate clauses. For example, the 1st one lists two nouns ("face" and "heart"), the 2nd and 4th one list adjectives and the 5th one lists adverbs. Is it possible to list them while contrasting them like in English, or do they have to be broken into separate clauses?
That said, that それでも in the 3rd one is actually a very helpful notion! Thank you very much! :>

Comment: Hey, thanks for your first post -- welcome to the community! This answer is in-depth, and answers the question asked, so well done! :) Your explanations could I think be a little clearer/briefer though, so maybe consider what sort of information you really need to include when answering a question. I think, in particular, if you can, writing in Japanese script rather than Romaji would be helpful for clarity.

Comment: @Ranquil Yes it is possible to list them while contrasting......but you have to learn the native accent for it....otherwise you will have a different tone like all foreigners do even if your sentences are correct........it all depends on how well you speak!!

Comment: @henreetee Your welcome......sure i will do my best!!!

Comment: I see. What kind of grammar should I use for that then? :>

Comment: https://takelessons.com/blog/japanese-grammar-rules-z05 ......check this out!!

Comment: That link... doesn't answer the question at all, it's just a few beginner tips.

Comment: @Ngangom, thank you very much for your efforts! as others have said, I think your answer is relevant to the question, wel done!! I added hiragana in your answer to make it more readable, feel free to drop the roumaji if you don't need it. There are some parts that I think they would be better left out of your answer,  because they do not address the question and hinder the reader's focus in the relevant information. In particular, I think that all the parts regarding the intonation should be  left out, unless the OP asks specifically for it.

Comment: Also, if you are not going to use your own expression "Sentence-Initial Conjunctions" latter in the answer, you don't need to make it up in the first place.

Comment: Also, what do you mean here "This is like the small gap we have after the word "best" " where does this "best" come from?

Comment: `I am very happy yet not satisfied. ->Translation: Watashi wa totemo manzoku shite iruga manzoku shite inai.`←もしかしてグーグル翻訳か何か使われました？ https://translate.google.co.uk/?um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&client=tw-ob#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=ja&text=I%20am%20very%20happy%20yet%20not%20satisfied.

Comment: You do add good explanation. But we don't provide translations. NO DIRECT TRANSLATIONS RULE: https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/799/29

Answer (score 0):

I am adding one more to Chocolate's list:

- で

> 怖い顔で優しい人
> a nice person albeit with a scary face

> 強面で優しい人
> a nice person albeit with a fierce look